# Joomla Template

Tags: templates, joomla

I would like to make a template on Joomla and the content looks like this: http://i40.tinypic.com/21l4to5.jpg

I need every article have an image and show the articles the way on the pic.
What components/modules do you suggest to achieve this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I suggest [zoo](http://www.yootheme.com/zoo/). I have worked with it on a project to integrate a "pet finder" on a local [humane society's website](http://www.foothillshumanesociety.org/our-animals/find-a-dog.html) and it looks like it could be tailored to meet your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it with the basic components of Joomla. One menu entry in blog layout with 5 rows and 3 cols and the intro of each article points to the detail page. No third party extensions needed here. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try virtuemart, it's very flexible. You can disable the price/cart feature and only use it to display the "products" along with other details you want about them.

Answer (score 0):

To develop content in image is not a good idea for content. Image should be show the full collapsed information like infographics and content should be developed itself's management system. Image content is not trackable by the search engines. So you may have no benefits from it. Using Content in [**Joomla Templates**](https://www.themexpert.com/joomla-templates) is the very easy than Writing on image.

Infographics can be made and it works really good, Why? Because infographics content is SEO friendly. But Just image content can not be tracked by Google or search Engines.

Answer (score -1):

I worked with extension Latest News Enhanced.

> Latest News Enhanced is an all-in-one news/articles module presenting
>   the latest, future (not pending), featured, popular or random articles
>   in a consistent professional fashion.
>
> - multiple ways to select news articles (standard Joomla! or K2): by    categories, by tags, by author, ...,
> - exclude/include specific articles,
> - show related items (through keywords or tags matching),
> - configure items with images from the article or calendar,
> - link to articles from the title and/or 'read more' links (in full    page or popup),
> - style items from a responsive-ready design,
> - use a minimum width to limit how small an item can be when resized,
> - crop and resize the pictures to fit the configuration (thumbnails can    be stored in /images),
> - style images with hover effects,
> - limit the into text to be shown,
> - add detailed information (author, hits, ratings, categories, date,    time, keywords),
> - format dates and times,
> - add pagination,
> - style buttons and pagination with Bootstrap,
> - enjoy a clean, easy to understand user interface,
> - cache the created on-the-fly stylesheets and scripts for faster    loading...

For more information and download check [extension page](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/latest-news-enhanced) at Joomla Extension Directory

It is highly customisable and free version is enough for most user.

Comment: Sorry for incorrect post, this is my first day on this site :)  I edited my answer, please check if it’s correct now. Thank You!